# InnerHTML Update Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "myurlhere.php", true );
xmlHttp.send();
var display = document.getElementById("display");
display.innerHTML = xmlHttp.response;
```

This is my code. This code is part of a function that is executed onclick of a button. It does do that AJAX request, however the innerHTML is not updated. Here's where it gets really weird. I go into my browser, go to the JS console, and type in `display.innerHTML = xmlHttp.response;`. Then it updates. I make a second button, with `display.innerHTML = xmlHttp.response;` as the onclick event... then it happens. But if I put it as a second line of the onclick event of the first button? No luck. How can I fix this confounding issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is because xmlHttp is async. You need to do the modification ***after*** the response has arrived. Which it has in the duration you take to type that in the js console.

You need to set the inner html in the onload event:

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "myurlhere.php", true );
xmlHttp.onload = function(e) {
  var display = document.getElementById("display");
  display.innerHTML = xmlHttp.response;  
}
xmlHttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `true` to send asynchronously. That means the rest of your code is being executed while waiting for your response. In other words, you're trying to insert data into your html before actually getting that data from the server. So you need a callback to fire off once you get that data:

```
xmlHttp.onload=function(e) {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;  
}
```